# I am converting byte array to video, and storing it to local machine. And want to view that Videos in my web app

Tags: html, video

I am converting byte array to video, and storing it to local machine.And want to view that Videos in my web app ,I am trying it using video tag of HTML5 .But its not allowing me to access videos from local machine.

`<video id="video" src=" video path from my local directory " controls autoplay></video>`

How to achieve this?

Comment: if you type the path of the video into your browser does it work? is the webpage being served from the same path? is the web page being served as a file:// or http:// ?

Comment: yes i am  able to  open it using below path:    _file:///C:/Users/empId/AppData/Local/Temp/Temp/STREAMED_VIDEOS/450798830133393_video.mp4_

Comment: is that the same path that you're opening the webpage from? does it work if you put the video in the same folder?

Comment: Yes ,I want to open the same path on my webpage. U can consider it like this : `<video src=" file:///C:/Users/empId/AppData/Local/Temp/Temp/STREAMED_VIDE‌​OS/450798830133393_v‌​ideo.mp4" controls ></video>`

Comment: I am not getting your second question : _does it work if you put the video in the same folder?_

Comment: if the video is in the same place as your HTML page does it work (adjusting the path as needed)

Comment: yes..it works fine when I keep my video file in context path of project , But I don't want these videos there.I want to read it from local directory. that's the problem .

Comment: a web server can only deliver from within the context it has access to.

Comment: Ohh ..then any other option for it ,except adding videos in context path.

Comment: As a option to this ,I am viewing videos directly on browser by writing output stream to servlet response .

Answer (score 0):

After googling,I found that we cant give file path starts as "file:///C:/myfilepath" for "src" attribute of html5 due to security issues.Because browser will consider that you are trying do access the clients machine . And will not allow you to do it.

So If you want view the video stored on your server machine, call any controller/servlet from you "src" attribute and write that video in the response. I mean get videos through http response.

**HTML Code :**

```
<video id="video" src="http://locallhost:8080/getVideoController?filename=yourFileName" controls autoplay></video>
```

**JAVA Code :**

```
 @WebServlet("/fileservlet")
 public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException
     {
            // Get requested file by path info.
            String filename = request.getParameter("filename");
            System.err.println("filename : "+filename);
            String requestedFile = "";

            requestedFile = "D:\\inputfiles\\"+ filename ;

           File file = new File(requestedFile);

            // Check if file actually exists in filesystem.
            if (!file.exists()) {
                // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning page, or 
                //just ignore it.
                System.out.println("file not exist");
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
                return;
            }

            // Get content type by filename.
            String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName());
            System.err.println("Content type :_>>"+ contentType);
            // If content type is unknown, then set the default value.

            if (contentType == null) {
                contentType = "application/octet-stream";
            }

            // Init servlet response.
            response.reset();
            response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            response.setContentType(contentType);
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));

            BufferedInputStream input = null;
            BufferedOutputStream output = null;

            try {
                // Open streams.
                input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), 
                DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), 
                DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
                // Write file contents to response.
                byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
                int length;
                while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
            } finally {
                // Gently close streams.
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            }

   }
  }
```